# Как настроить urlManager?

Tags: yii2

Есть таблица категорий товаров с полями:

**cat_id:** индекс категории
**cat_name:** название категории
**parentcat_id:** индекс родительской категории
**alias:** часть адреса - транслитерация названия категории (может содержать и буквы и цифры).
Например она содержит категории:

```
  cat_id | cat_name | parentcat_id | alias
-------------------------------------------------
    1      Каталог     0             catalog
    2    Телевизоры    1               tele
    3        Авто      1               avto
    4      Авто BMW    3               bmw
    5      Дизельные   4              dizel
```

Уровней вложенности 4 (это на практике, а в теории бесконечно).
Все материалы категории выводятся контроллером CategoryController, action: view($alias)
То есть если ввести адрес:

- site.ru/catalog/tele - нужно отловить $alias=tele и передать в экшн
- site.ru/catalog/avto/bmw - $alias=bmw
- site.ru/catalog/bmw/dizel - $alias=dizel

Как будут выглядеть правила UrlManager для данного случая?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала мы заворачиваем URL вида `/catalog/всё_остальное_как_алиас` в этот контроллер

```
'catalog/<alias:\.+>' => 'category/view',
```

А потом в контроллере находим последнюю часть (нужный нам `alias`) и по нему ищем категорию:

```
public function actionView($alias)
{
    $alias = basename($alias, '/');
    $category = Category::model()->findByAttributes(['alias' => $alias]);
    // остальной код для вывода категории
}
```

Но это будет правильно работать только в том случае, если у вас уникальный `alias` в БД.

Comment: а если пользователь изменит alias "catalog" на другой, то придется вносить правки в код? тут нужен какойто универсальный набор правил, вопрос какой))

Comment: @Monitorkin не понял вопроса.

Comment: 'category/<alias:\.+>' => 'category/view', - эта строка правильная? Или должно быть так: 'catalog/<alias:\.+>' => 'category/view'?

Comment: Должно быть 'catalog', поторопился написать ответ, вы правы.

Comment: тогда получается, слово "catalog" из 'catalog/<alias:\.+>' должно присутствовать во всех url, и если в базе ктото поменяет алиас "catalog" на например "cat1", то мы уже не попадаем.., то есть вместо "catalog" должно быть еще какоето правило